# How to fix batch which is adding '1' before executing program

Tags: batch-file

I've got a batch file on PC with Windows XP SP3 running on it. Everything is working well, but when i copy this program with other needed files with second PC with Windows XP SP3, it can't execute code. It adds '1' before '>>' chars. File is written in notepad with ANSI Encoding.

I tried to change encoding, without result. Also adding `chcp 65001` didn't work. Adding spacebars after `>>` didn't work too.

```
echo ------------------------------------- >> log.txt
date /t >> log.txt
```

Code should execute and close command prompt, but it shows:

```
echo ------------------------------------- 1>> log.txt
date /t 1>> log.txt
```

Comment: There's nothing to fix, the output is 100% correct, you are just used to using lazy redirection operators, because `1>` is the default, the `1` isn't essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn `echo`ing `off`, then do it like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
(   Echo -------------------------------------
    Date /T) > "log.txt"
```

Or:

```bat
@Echo Off
(   Echo -------------------------------------
    Date /T) 1> "log.txt"
```

In both cases, if `-------------------------------------` isn't supposed to be the first line of `log.txt`, *(i.e. it already has content)*, then change **`>`** to **`>>`**.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This worked for me, 1 isnt displayed now. I tought that's why my program isn't running well, but the issue differen - activated windows firewall.  I forgot about such a elementary thing. However, thank You for fast answer.